# Do modern airliner wings suffer from a "gap" in safe AOA flight?

Tags: aircraft-design

The supercritical wing is really great for cruising at high Mach numbers with little change in AOA.

Comment: Slats do not create more lift at constant AoA. They allow for higher AoA without stalling.

Comment: The problems with MCAS have all had to do with its failure modes - i.e. it handled a failed AoA sensor very badly.  With valid inputs, MCAS activates only in rare circumstances and its presence doesn't suggest anything even vaguely like what you posit. No, there is no "gap" as suggested.

Comment: this question has 3 answers, that's why the system will not let you delete it. a moderator needs a good reason to overrule the system. such a reason seems not to be present here, that's why your request cannot be fulfilled. ask on meta if you want to push it further.

Answer (score 4):

It's kind of a solution in search of a problem.  Slats create massive drag and some vibration and there is simply no point in leaving them extended at high speeds when there is plenty of Alpha margin with the clean wing. There really isn't any point.

You have an airplane that typically stalls clean at around 120-140kt.  You are cruising at 240kt indicated at the low end, maybe up to 290-300 kt indicated at the high end. What is the point of having slats out?  If the airplane has nasty stall behaviour, well that's the stick pusher's job.

In any case, if you built an airplane with extendable slats that can handle Vmo, which is what you would have to do, forget about being able to get to Vmo in the first place, unless you had afterburners or something, and then you'd have to replace half the passengers with fuel tanks.

If you really wanted to do something like that, you wouldn't build slats that stay out at high speed, you would just make the leading edges slotted, which used to be a popular thing on light aircraft in the 40s.  Still, on a high speed aircraft a massive drag producer, and possibly Mach related issues too with slightly accelerated air flowing up through the slot - who knows.

Even the light aircraft business had abandoned LE slots by the mid 50s except for special STOL cases.

Comment: I'm all for supercriticals in cruise!  They are the best high Mach subsonic wing going, but begin to lose what little lift to drag ratio they have at 5 degrees AOA, many stalling past 12 degrees.  This is clearly not a maneuvering wing, Whitcomb himself added camber to them to improve lower speed/higher AOA performance.  The suggestion is to use power and more camber to improve climbing efficiency  at lower AOA to stay away from stall.

Comment: No it is horribly inefficient and again there is no practical point.  The drag of slats is absolutely massive.  You aren't going around maneuvering in combat pulling 7G and loading the wing to near stall AOA at high speed in an airliner, and that would be the only point.

Answer (score 1):

"Given recent concerns and extensive efforts to monitor and control AOA (stick shakers and MCAS), would it make sense to look into developing slats that could remain deployed up to cruising altitude"-- no it would not.

Comment: This really isn't an appropriate answer, please add some explanation.

Comment: I don't disagree, but it would be appropriate to explain _why_ it would not.

Comment: It's it kind of logical: if that was a better design, why not make the high lift devices part of the main wing anyways? If they are "needed up to cruising altitude", they obviously aren't that bad on cruising altitude (it's not like something magically changes). So to make it cheaper just use HLD all the way and make them static.

Comment: This may not be the answer this question needs, but it certainly is the answer it deserves.

Answer (score 1):

Flaps and Slats are high drag devices and only added where they are needed to reduce landing and takeoff distances. Their real purpose is to reduce approach speeds. They do this by changing an efficient high speed, low drag wing into a slow speed, high drag wing. To use them in cruise would make the aircraft LESS efficient, not more efficient.

While most aircraft have Flaps, and many have both Flaps and Slats, some aircraft have NO Flaps and NO Slats. (These are generally low speed aircraft where takeoff and landing distances are not a factor)

Any aircraft can land just fine without Flaps and Slats. This is routinely demonstrated in Simulator training for Flap and Slat failures. Without Flaps and Slats the approach speeds are much higher, and this which results in much longer landing distances. But when correctly done it is 100% safe to land without Flaps and Slats.

Comment: Slats are specifically designed (going back to the Sabre Jet(and further, if you look)) to reduce the AOA of a swept wing tip, preventing it from stalling first.  But certainly we can agree, while higher flaps ARE for drag, a lower slat and flap setting, with more power, can safely increase lift, or give the same lift at lower AOA.

Comment: The Sabre has automatic slats (basically sucked out) that only extend at high AOA, and at high speed this happens only during combat maneuvering.  Airliners don't go around pulling 7G turns at 250kt.  High speed stalls are simply not an issue from any rational safety perspective.  You are proposing a solution in search of a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @John K  Maneuvering Characteristics Augmentation System, MCAS, only operates in manual, flaps up flight, and returns the trim to pre-stall condition after AOA drops 0.5 below activation angle.  Hardly "a solution in search of a problem".  MCAS  "commands nose down stabilizer during steep turns with elevated load factors"  Source: Skybrary.

Comment: You are describing a special case and in any case, MCAS is NOT to correct a dangerous deficiency in the MAX's handing.  It is only to make the airplane's behaviour mimic earlier 737s.  If Boeing decided to accept a separate type rating for the MAX, MCAS would not have been required in the first place and the MAX's handling qualities would have been perfectly certifiable as is.